Can there exist a set of all transitive sets in a model of NF or NFU?
Is it consistent with $\sf NF$ or $\sf NFU$ to have a set of all transitive sets? Formally:
$\exists t \forall x (x \in t \leftrightarrow x \text { is transitive})$
Where "$x$ is transitive" means that every element of $x$ is a subset of $x$.

No. See Proposition 2.1.16 in Forster's book "Set Theory with a Universal Set: Exploring an Untyped Universe".

Could you perhaps add a sketch of the argument? Or is it too complicated?

@EmilJeřábek, the idea of the proof is that if we have that set then we can easily have a transitive closure for each set (since that would be stratified), then the set ${x: x \notin TC({ {y} \mid y \in x})}$ would be paradoxical. Where $TC$ stand for the transitive closure operator. An unpublished proof of Boffa.
